# Populating asp.net table from data from database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a few questions concerning populating a table from a datatable in asp.net

I have pulled data correctly from my database but now I have a table with data in it. How do I go about populating my asp.net Table control? I understand how to access the rows and columns data but don't know how to "bind" or "populate" the Table control.

I looked into using a gridview but some people said they load slow so I am avoiding that.

Any help would be much appreciated

HTML

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="table" CssClass="table">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Cell 1 Header</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>Cell 2 Header</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell ID="cell1"></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell ID="cell2"></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

C#

```
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConnection);
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        DataTable table = dataSet.Tables[0];

        // Loop through rows
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            // Loop through columns
            foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns){

            }
        }
```

Comment: So what is wrong with a gridview? I wouldn't avoid that if it were me. I have never once used a table control but I don't think they can be bound which rather cripples it as a viable tool for this kind of thing.

Comment: You can still use a Table if you want, you just need something to create the data, such as a Repeater.

Comment: How do I use a repeater

Answer (score 2):

I'm giving you code, how to use Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTable" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="table">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%"><%# Eval("identifier") %></td>
            <td width="*"><%# Eval("value") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And your code behind:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select identifier, value from table_name", con);

try{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    rptTable.DataSource = ds;
    rptTable.DataBind();
}
catch(Exception ex){
    //...
}
finally{
    con.Close();
}
```

Of course, you have to change table's design and sql query as you need. I just showed basic structure

Comment: `rptTable` is giving error how it should be declared in the C# code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
private void GenerateTable()
{
    DataTable dt = this.GetData(); //GetData returns your datatable from sql
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row); 
    }
}
```